# Insert into with output clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, output-clause

```
INSERT INTO Table1(group, account)

OUTPUT inserted.Id, B.title, B.amount 
INTO Table2(id2, title, amount) 

SELECT A.*,
         B.title,
           B.amount,
            B.id2    
FROM Table1 AS A

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  title,
          amount,
           id2
 FROM Table2) AS B
 ON A.id = B.id2
```

i'm stuck with this..i have `two join tables` and what i want is to copy the same set of data from `table1` to itself and copy the new id of the newly copied data from `table1` to `table2` column `id2` by using `OUTPUT` clause.

but now with the query above i cant get through the column that i needed..how can i insert column `B.title` & `B.amount` to `table2` ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - [Is it possible to for SQL Output clause to return a column not being inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10949730/1048425)

Comment: That query won't run anyway; `GROUP` is a reserved word in SQL Server. If you have a column called `group` you have to quote it: `[group]`.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to `INSERT`? Your `INSERT` clause has only 2 columns `group` and `account,` however, your `SELECT` has all of `A`'s column, as well as `title`, `amount`, and `id2` from `B`. 3 + *x* columns doesn't fit into 2. Also, you're trying to insert the data from `Table2` back into `table2` by use of the `INTO` clause? That makes no sense. What are you *really* trying to do here? Explain your goal, and provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If table 1 and table 2 have a 1:1 relationship, and no foreign key exists between the two then you *could* do this in a single statement:

```
MERGE Table1 AS a 
USING
(   SELECT  A.[group], A.account, B.title, B.amount, B.id2    
    FROM    Table1 AS A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS B
                ON A.id = B.id2
) AS b
    ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([group], account)
    VALUES (b.[group], b.account)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, B.title, B.amount 
    INTO Table2(id2, title, amount);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0cbff1/1)**

Realistically though, if your tables are related they should have a foreign key, and in most cases they won't be 1:1, rather 1:n.

In which case you would still need to use `MERGE` to caputre both the new ID and the old ID, but you would then need to capture this mapping in a temporary table before performing a second insert to Table2:

```
DECLARE @Map TABLE (OldID INT NOT NULL, NewID INT NOT NULL);

MERGE Table1 AS a 
USING
(   SELECT  A.ID, A.[group], A.account  
    FROM    Table1 AS A
) AS b
    ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([group], account)
    VALUES (b.[group], b.account)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, b.ID
    INTO @Map(NewID, OldID);

INSERT Table2 (id2, title, amount)
SELECT  m.NewID, b.title, b.amount
FROM    @Map AS m
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS b
            ON b.ID2 = m.OldID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9995a2/3)**