# Insert Into: Returns inserted records

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2017

I'm trying to insert some new records into a table and return the inserted records.

```sql
DECLARE @newRecords TABLE
                    (
                        Id         INT          NULL,
                        Col1       VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
                        Col2       VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
                        ForeignKey VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
                    )

INSERT INTO @newRecords
    SELECT ColA AS Col1, ColB AS Col2, Key AS ForeignKey 
    FROM SomeTable;

INSERT INTO PrimaryTable(Col1, Col2)
OUTPUT inserted* INTO @newRecords
    SELECT Col1, Col2 
    FROM @newRecords;
```

The problem is that outputting the inserted records via the `OUTPUT` statement causes an error because the column `ForeignKey` does not exist in `PrimaryTable`. I am worried about outputting the records to a second temp table because I have no good means of joining the data from `PrimaryTable` to the `@newRecords` table.

Ideally what I would like to see happen is:

1. The new records are populated into the `@newRecords` temp table from `SomeOtherTable`
2. The appropriate columns from the `@newRecords` temp table are then inserted into the `PrimaryTable`
3. Finally the primary keys that were assigned to the newly inserted records in the `PrimaryTable` are updated into the `@newRecords.Id` column so that I can go on and do some additional record creations

I've tried messing around with the `MERGE` statement as well as seeing if I could add some additional statements to the `OUTPUT` statement but either it's not possible or (more likely) I am not using the syntax correctly.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `The problem is that outputting the inserted records via the OUTPUT statement causes an error because the field ForeignKey does not exist in the PrimaryTable` This has nothing to do with the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: You can use `output` with `merge` to store columns beyond those being inserted. If you edit your question to include your `merge` statement, and any applicable DDL, we ought to be able to help with it. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950418/92546) answer may provide a clue.

Comment: You should be first inserting the records into the referenced table and only then you can insert them into the referencing table. I think that if you could [edit] your question to include a [mcve] containing the relevant tables DDL, some sample data as DML and expected results, it would help to clarify it very much.