# How to handle outputting values not included in SQL insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing an import process which will import data from one (somewhat legacy) database to another. The import process takes one flat table with the source data. I have this populating a temp table (`#SourcePersonAccount`) at the start. The goal is to distribute this data into three destination tables (`dbo.Person`, `dbo.Account` & `dbo.PersonAccount`). This runs within a trigger on a table use SQL Server Replication, so needs to run quickly.

```
#SourcePersonAccount([AccountNumber], [CompanyId], [TargetPersonId], [TargetAccountId]);
dbo.Person ([Id] pk identity(1,1), [CompanyId], ...);
dbo.Account ([Id] pk identity(1,1), [AccountNumber], ...);
dbo.PersonAccount ([Id], [PersonId] fk_Person_Id, [AccountId] fk_Account_Id);
```

In my code, I have the `TargetPersonId` already populated in the `#SourcePersonAccount` temp table. All that's left is to 1) insert into `dbo.Account`, 2) update `#SourcePersonAccount` with the inserted `dbo.Account.Id` value, 3) insert into `dbo.PersonAccount`.

One of the challenges is that the `AccountNumber` and `CompanyId` make up a composite primary key of the source table, so both are needed to join properly on the `#SourcePersonAccount` temp table.

I have seen threads addressing similar issues to a certain extent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949730/is-it-possible-to-for-sql-output-clause-to-return-a-column-not-being-inserted) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cf1e38e-a29b-4ad7-abc7-b9fe2b987698/insert-into-using-select-with-output-into-multipart-identifier-could-not-be-bound?forum=transactsql) which did not solve my particular problem, mostly due to performance issues.

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949730/is-it-possible-to-for-sql-output-clause-to-return-a-column-not-being-inserted), the `OUTPUT` clause cannot output columns that were not included in the insert, so that is not an option here.

One solution I saw that technically can give the desired output (I can't find the link to where I found the suggestion) while using the `OUTPUT` clause is to actually add and drop a column within the query.

```
DECLARE @PersonAccountTbl TABLE ([AccountId] INT, [AccountNumber] INT, [CompanyId] INT);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account]
    ADD [CompanyId] INT NULL;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Account]
    ([AccountNumber], [CompanyId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[AccountNumber], INSERTED.[CompanyId]
INTO @PersonAccountTbl
SELECT
    [AccountNumber], [CompanyId]
FROM #SourcePersonAccount
WHERE
    [TargetAccountId] IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account]
    DROP COLUMN [CompanyId];
```

This is not a viable option for my situation.

I tried using `MERGE` as every thread I've found on this issue recommends using it. I do not like `MERGE` for [a few reasons](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). I tried it anyways; the below code gives the desired output, but ended up being much too slow for my purposes.

```
DECLARE @PersonAccountTbl TABLE ([AccountId] INT, [AccountNumber] INT, [CompanyId] INT);

MERGE INTO [dbo].[Account] a
USING #SourcePersonAccount spa
    ON spa.[TargetAccountId] IS NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
        ([AccountNumber])
    VALUES
        (spa.[AccountNumber])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[AccountNumber], spa.[CompanyId]
    INTO @PersonAccountTbl ([AccountId], [AccountNumber], [CompanyId]);

UPDATE spa
    SET spa.[TargetAccountId] = pat.[AccountId]
FROM #SourcePersonAccount spa
JOIN @PersonAccountTbl pat
    ON pat.[AccountNumber] = spa.[AccountNumber]
    AND pat.[CompanyId] = spa.[CompanyId];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersonAccount]
    ([PersonId], [AccountId])
SELECT
    spa.[TargetPersonId], spa.[TargetAccountId]
FROM #SourcePersonAccount spa
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PersonAccount] pa
    ON pa.[PersonId] = spa.[TargetPersonId]
    AND pa.[AccountId] = spa.[TargetAccountId]
WHERE
    pa.[Id] IS NULL;
```

Is there a way **other than** `MERGE` or adding/dropping a column to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of an IDENTITY column.  Then you can assign the IDs to a temp table or table variable before you INSERT the data.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you