# Using OUTPUT INTO with from_table_name in an INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, output-clause

[Microsoft's OUTPUT Clause documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says that you are allowed to use *from_table_name* in the OUTPUT clause's column name.

There are two examples of this:

- [Using OUTPUT INTO with from_table_name in an UPDATE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-using-output-into-with-from_table_name-in-an-update-statement)
- [Using OUTPUT INTO with from_table_name in a DELETE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-using-output-into-with-from_table_name-in-a-delete-statement)

Is it possible to also use it in an *INSERT statement*?

```sql
INSERT INTO T ( [Name] )
OUTPUT S.Code, inserted.Id INTO @TMP -- The multi-part identifier "S.Code" could not be bound.
SELECT [Name] FROM S;
```

#### Failing example using table variables

```sql
-- A table to insert into.
DECLARE @Item TABLE (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] varchar(100)
);
-- A table variable to store inserted Ids and related Codes
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    Code varchar(10),
    ItemId  int
);
-- Insert some new items
WITH S ([Name], Code) AS (
    SELECT 'First', 'foo'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Second', 'bar'
    -- Etc.
)
INSERT INTO @Item ( [Name] )
OUTPUT S.Code, inserted.Id INTO @T -- The multi-part identifier "S.Code" could not be bound.
SELECT [Name] FROM S;
```

Comment: source columns which are not inserted can be referenced/output only for MERGE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to for SQL Output clause to return a column not being inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949730/is-it-possible-to-for-sql-output-clause-to-return-a-column-not-being-inserted)

Comment: @SMor Yes, it does! That is a duplicate answer I failed to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because an INSERT doesn't have a FROM; it has a set of values that are prepared either by the VALUES keyword, or from a query (and even though that query has a FROM, you should conceive that it's already been run and turned into a block of values by the time the insert is done; there is no `s.code` any more)

If you want to output something from the table that drove the insert you'll need to use a merge statement that never matches any records (so it's only inserting) instead, or perhaps insert all your data into @tmp and then insert from @tmp into the real table - @tmp will thus still be the record of rows that were inserted, it's just that it was created to drive the insert rather than as a consequence of it (caveats that it wouldn't contain calculated columns)