# OUTPUTting fields from an INSERT...SELECT query using fields from the SELECT results

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to populate an association table with the output from an `INSERT...SELECT` query in *Microsoft SQL Server*, but I'm getting errors and can't find a workaround.

This is the most minimal, reproducible problem I can come up with: I have a table of `things` defined as:

```tsql
CREATE TABLE dbo.things(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name nvarchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

that is already populated. To allow the example to work, use this:

```tsql
INSERT INTO dbo.things(
    name
)
VALUES('Thing1'),('Thing2'),('Thing3');
```

Now I have a table of widgets:

```tsql
CREATE TABLE dbo.widgets(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    description nvarchar(255) NULL
);
```

and a further table that associates `thing`s and `widget`s in a *many-to-many* manner:

```tsql
CREATE TABLE dbo.thing_widget_associations(
    thing_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.things(id),
    widget_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.widgets(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(
        thing_id,
        widget_id
    )
);
```

However, each `thing` needs to have at least one `widget` association, but some of the necessary `widget`s are missing, so I'd like to create them, then associate them with the corresponding `thing` all in the same query.

Here's what I tried:

```tsql
INSERT INTO dbo.widgets(
    description
)
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.id, -- Identifier of the newly created widget.
    t.id -- Identify of the associated thing. <- Doesn't work. I get error here.
INTO dbo.thing_widget_associations(
    widget_id,
    thing_id
)
SELECT
    'Default widget for thing ' + t.name
FROM dbo.thing_widget_associations AS twa
RIGHT JOIN dbo.things AS t
    ON twa.thing_id = t.id
WHERE twa.thing_id IS NULL;
```

However, when I try to run this query, I get the following:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "t.id" could not be bound.
Msg 332, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The target table 'dbo.thing_widget_associations' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK__thing_wid__thing__5165187F'.
```

From what I've seen, it doesn't seem possible to use a field from a table queried as part of the `INSERT` query in the `OUTPUT` clause, and I think that's what the first error refers to. However, if I omit the `OUTPUT` clause, then I can't associate each created `widget` with the `thing` used to create it.

Can anyone also explain the second error, which has completely passed me by? Is that a consequence of the first error?

Bottom line: is there a way to do this? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Use `merge`. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949730/is-it-possible-to-for-sql-output-clause-to-return-a-column-not-being-inserted)

Comment: Thanks, @Stu! Wow! I would never have guessed that in a million years! Any chance you could write that up as the answer, and I'll accept it immediately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `output` of an `insert` can refer to just the `inserted` and `deleted` tables. Using `merge` is the workaround.

Here is how to restructure with `merge`

```
merge dbo.widgets t
using (
    select 'Default widget for thing ' + t.name w, t.id
    from dbo.things as t
    left join dbo.thing_widget_associations twa on twa.thing_id = t.id
    where twa.thing_id is null
)s on 1=0
when not matched then 
insert (description) values (s.w)
output INSERTED.id, s.id 
into dbo.thing_widget_associations(widget_id, thing_id);
```

note that with the sample table's constraints, this generates an error `The target table 'dbo.thing_widget_associations' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK__thing_wid__thing__2BFE89A6'.`

Therefore I've tested without these present on the table.